# Proving that $\frac{1}{a_1....a_n} \geq (n-1)^n $ under certain conditions

Tags: inequality

> Suppose $a_k > 0$ for $k=1,...,n$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{1+a_k} =
>  n-1 $. Prove that
>
> $$ \prod_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{a_k} \geq (n-1)^n $$

### Proof:

Taking $log$ in both sides we obtain that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n  \log(1/a_k) \geq n \log (n-1) $$

And by hypothesis, it be enough if we can prove

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \log \left( \dfrac{1}{a_k } \right) \geq n \log \left( \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{1+a_k} \right) $$

I dont see how to prove this. But, we go back to the beginning and apply Harmonic-Geometric mean ineq to $( \prod 1/a_k )^{1/n} $, we obtain

$$ \left( \prod_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{a_k} \right)^{1/n} \geq \dfrac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k } \geq \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{1+a_k} = n -1 $$

and this would be the end but we still to prove that

$$ n \geq (a_1+.... + a_n) \left( \dfrac{1}{1+a_1} + ... + \dfrac{1}{1+a_n} \right) $$

but I am unable to prove this. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what you are trying to prove $n \geq (a_1+.... + a_n) \left( \dfrac{1}{1+a_1} + ... + \dfrac{1}{1+a_n} \right)\ $is not true. I give you a contradiction. what you want to prove is same as proving $ \ \frac{n}{n-1}\geq (a_1+.... + a_n) $. Let us assume $\ n\geq2\ $. You can safely assume one of the variables, let's say $ a_1$ to be $n$ and rest other such that they follow $a_k>0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{1+a_k} = n-1$. But see here that the sum $(a_1+.... + a_n)\geq n\geq \dfrac{n}{n-1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that by Titu's lemma applied to the condition, we have $ \sum a_i \geq \frac{n}{n-1} $, so your HM-GM is too strong already.

---

The condition is equivalent to $\sum \frac{1}{ 1 + \frac{1}{a_i}} = 1$.

> $ \sum \frac{1}{ 1 + 1/a_i } =  \sum \frac{ a_i } { 1 + a_i }  = \sum 1 - \frac{1}{1+a_i } = n - (n-1) = 1.$

Let $ b_i = \frac{1}{ 1 + \frac{1}{a_i}}$, so $ \frac{1}{a_i} = \frac{1-b_i } { b_i} $ and $ \sum b_i = 1$.

Thus $ \prod \frac{1}{a_i} = \prod \frac{ 1 - b_ i } { b_i } = \prod \frac{ \sum_{j\neq i }  b_j } { b_i } \geq \prod \frac{ (n-1) \prod_{i\neq j } b_j ^ \frac{1}{n-1} } { b_i }  = (n-1)^n $.

---

Several variants of this problem has appeared in various olympiads.

E.g. Under the same conditions, show that $ \sum \frac{1}{ \sqrt{a_i} } \geq (n-1) \sum \sqrt{a_i} $

Comment: Thanks! I am afraid I cant see how $\sum \dfrac{1}{1+1/a_i} = 1 $. Can you explain a little bit? thanks

Comment: What have you tried? It's a pretty direct algebraic manipulation. Hint: Multiply by $ \frac{a_i } { a_i}$.

Comment: I got it. Sorry I dont have paper at hand. I am slow today